# PHP - DOMDocument - Get the previous element and his data attributes

Tags: php, xml, dom, nodes, domdocument

Hello I 'm trying to manage a DOMDocument from a string.
My string looks like that :

```
$String =
    <p>
        <div class="ST" data-start="1" data-end="5">
            <span>WORD1</span><span>WORD2</span>
        </div>
    </p>
    <p>
        WORD3 WORD4
    </p>
    <p>
        <div class="ST" data-start="6" data-end="10">
            <span>WORD5</span><span>WORD6</span>
        </div>
    </p>
```

My aim is to put words `WORD3` and `WORD4` in a `<div>` tag like `WORD1` `WORD2` and `WORD5` `WORD6` for the first and last `<p>` tags. Also, I need to get `data-start` `data-end` of the previous `p > div` and obtain finaly this:

```
$String =
        <p>
            <div class="ST" data-start="1" data-end="5">
                <span>WORD1</span><span>WORD2</span>
            </div>
        </p>
        <p>
            <div class="ST" data-start="1" data-end="5">
                WORD3 WORD4
            </div>
        </p>
        <p>
            <div class="ST" data-start="6" data-end="10">
                <span>WORD5</span><span>WORD6</span>
            </div>
        </p>
```

I managed to put WORD3 and WORD4 in a `<div>` but I don't know how to get the previous element `p > div` and get his attributes `data-start` and `data-end`...

My code:

```
public function reverseTransform($value) {

    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $dom->formatOutput = true;
    $dom->loadHTML($value); 

    $pTags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('p');

    $TagFull='';
    foreach ($pTags as $pTag) {
            $valuePTagFull = $this->DOMinnerHTML($pTag);
            if (strpos($valuePTagFull,'<div') === false) {
                $valuePTagFull = "<div class='st'>".$valuePTagFull."</div>";
            }
            $TagFull .= $valuePTagFull;

        }
    }

private function DOMinnerHTML(DOMNode $element)
    {
        $innerHTML = "";
        $children = $element->childNodes;
        foreach ($children as $child) {
            $innerHTML .= $element->ownerDocument->saveHTML($child);
        }
        return $innerHTML;
    }
```

In fact, for each `<p>` which have `WORDx` into but without `<div>` , I wrap `WORDx` in a `<div>` with `data-start` and `data-end` attributes of the previous `<p> >> <div>`

But how to select and get attributes from the previous element with DOM, XML or another way ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could get the last values of start end with regex but that will not be using DOM.

```
if (strpos($valuePTagFull,'<div') === false) {
                $valuePTagFull = "<div class='st' data-start=".$matches[1]." data-end=".$matches[2].">".$valuePTagFull."</div>";
            }
            else{
                preg_match('~<div[^>]*?class="ST"[^>]*?data-start="(\d*?)" data-end="(\d*?)">~',$valuePTagFull,$matches);
            }
            $TagFull .= $valuePTagFull;
```

Comment: hi! what is "$matches" at the 2nd line ?

Comment: @Zagloo Its an array including the 2 integers you need. This is not a good practice though, you might want to find alternate ways to get the div attributes.